# Using the FB API, can you share a link, but serve an image that is not on the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can post a photo IF I had the time to get an app approved. I can share a link that pulls in a photo from THAT page. The goal is to post a link that goes to X, but the image is hosted somewhere else.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible by using the JavaScript SDK and the Share Dialog. For example, I can do the following, which shares a link but with a custom image, name and caption. It basically overwrites all the OG data on my page.

```
function fb_share() {
    FB.ui( {
        method: 'feed',
        name: "Facebook API: Tracking Shares using the JavaScript SDK",
        link: "https://www.webniraj.com/2013/05/11/facebook-api-tracking-shares-using-the-javascript-sdk/",
        picture: "https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/557969.png",
        caption: "Tracking Facebook Shares on your website or application is a useful way of seeing how popular your articles are with your readers. In order to tracking Shares, you must used the Facebook JavaScript SDK."
    }, function( response ) {
        // do nothing
    } );

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button.share-btn').on( 'click', fb_share );
});
```

You can do the same thing in PHP if you have the `publish_actions` permission approved by Facebook. Both would produce the following result:

[image]

[Source](https://www.webniraj.com/2013/05/11/facebook-api-tracking-shares-using-the-javascript-sdk/)